# Getting the link I am redirected to

Tags: java, multithreading, url, proxy

I am using Java, and I want to send a request to a URL and then get the URL I am redirected to.

I would like the solution if it included the use of HttpClient and Requests as I already have used that past.

Comment: So what did you try? A redirect is normally a 301 or 302 response along with a new location, did you try to read that? (You might need to tell the client not to automatically follow redirects)

Comment: Please show us some code, what have you tried.

Comment: @Thomas I havent tried, can you tell me what I can do to try it? SHould I just send a request to that URL? and then How will it tell me what url it has been redirected to?

Comment: @tostao I tried sending a HttpRequest to the root URL (method: GET) it just sends me the HTML of the webpage. Any way to get the URL I am redirected to?

Comment: Read my comment again, I already added some hints on how to detect a redirect (maybe some additional research is needed but it should get you started). Basically first make sure the redirect is even happening, i.e. an indicator would be that if you run it in the browser the url changes. If it was just an internal proxy/forward you won't know whether there was an internal redirect or not.

Comment: @Thomas But I want to get the url it will be redirected to, so isnt it better letting Follow Redirect on?

Comment: @Thomas it does redirect me I tried it in my browser

Comment: Also @Thomas I dont want to detect the redirect, I want to get the URL of the redirect cause I am fully sure the redirect will happen every time you go to the URL

Comment: "so isnt it better letting Follow Redirect on?" - depends, if you want the page you got redirected to then yes. But if you want the url you need to stop and examine the result. In most cases you'd get a 301, 302 or 303 status with the new url (which the client/browser might follow automatically) or you actually get the HTML page which contains a redirect header, some javascript etc. - this is likely not directly evaluated by a http client and you might have to do the parsing yourself.

Comment: Man you are  so smart, that was really helpful, I am dumb, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using a bit of cURL.
So what I do is I execute `curl URL` and it shows me the page structure of the URL and the page structure is just an anchor element So I parse the link from it .